# understanding a SPI data sheet - FIFO size versus recieve register size

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, spi, digital-communications

My question is in relation to the difference between a SPI recieve register size and a FIFO.

For example - I am looking at the SPI datasheet for 2 devices (1) a spi IP for an FPGA and (2) the SPI controller on an MCU.

The datasheet for the FPGA (Altera - soft processor) says that SPI receiving holding register can be up to 32 bits on size. Here is the datasheet for the fpga

Here is the datasheet for the MCU (intel C1000 mcu). It says that it has up to 32 bit frame size. 
[image: FPGA spi core datasheet]

But it also says that it has "FIFO mode support with 16B TX and RX FIFOs made from 4 entries of 32bits wide" - what does this mean?
[image: mcu spi part1]

Comment: The most typical meaning for such a spec would be to say that each FIFO can either hold 16 entries of up to 8 bits each or 4 entries of up to 32 bits each.  The FIFOs could likely also hold 8 entries of up to 16 bits each.  While a 128-bit capacity could in theory hold twelve 10-bit entries or five 24-bit entries, the description suggests that entries can cross neither 8-bit nor 32-bit boundaries, thus limiting the system to eight 10-bit entries (stored using two bytes each), or four 24-bit entries (one 32-bit word each).

Answer (score 1):

Receive register size = The number of bits per transfer. The minimum amount of data that can be sent.

Receive FIFO size = The number of transfers that can be buffered up waiting for the CPU to read them before data is lost. Since the transfer size is variable this is done using a fixed amount of memory rather than holding a fixed number of transfers in order to avoid wasted memory. The number of transfers stored will depend upon the transfer size.

Normally SPI buses are used in an interrupt based setup, once a transfer is complete an interrupt is generated. The CPU then stops what it is doing, copies the received data into a software buffer and then either processes it or sets a flag that there is new data and returns to what it was going before.

But SPI can run very fast, what happens if the CPU can't drop everything and read the data before the next transfer comes in? That's where the receive FIFO comes in. It allows the hardware to buffer up multiple transfers so that the CPU doesn't have to respond quite so quickly. Depending upon the amount of data being sent it may even make it practical to use a polled system rather than interrupts.